# Why does memtest86+ restart immediately when I click start test?

Tags: live-cd, memtest

I have tried memtest86+ from different liveCDs but when I click on start....it reboots. My laptop has been kinda slow lately...so I decided to test it and this is what happened. It is really weird. Is there a way to find out what causes the problem? Or what went wrong on the hardware side of my laptop?

**UPDATE: I individually tested the 2 memory sticks and it restarted in both of the cases. I highly doubt both memory sticks are corrupted. How can they both get corrupted at the same time. Weird.**

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be the signal of the presence of a big problem on your RAM.

How many slots of RAM do you have?

If more than one, you can physically remove one of them, then try again with memtest+.
If still not working, remount it, unmount another slot and try memtest+, and so on until you find the damaged one. When you find it, you can either decide to remain with less RAM or buy another one. If the latter, take the damaged one to the store and buy another similar, otherwise it might happen that your BIOS won't recognize the whole RAM, but just a part of it.

If you have only one slot, the unique is to find a friend which lend you one of her/his and do again the memtest+.

If you do not find a damaged RAM (aka all the previous memtest+ fail / go right) the problem is somewhere else, maybe directly with the Motherboard.
In this case I suggest that you take your pc to a store.

**WARNING**: if your pc is still under warranty avoid any of the above and take it where you bought it, because opening it to remove the RAM will cause the warranty to become void.

Comment: no warranty...unfortunately. I have tested the 2 memory stick...one by one...and it does the same. It restarts with both sticks individually plugged. No idea what it could be. I installed Phronix Test Suite...but it is for advanced users. I dont understand a thing of what it says after I have run the test.

Comment: I don't think he had any issue with memory (see my answer)